# Usercontrol with treeview selected event that refreshed another usercontrol not working

Tags: wpf, events, user-controls, methods

I'm relatively new to WPF programming and can't seem to get this working correctly.  This is in my mind something rather simplistic that i would like to get working so I didn't try the MVVM framework and decided to keep it simple.

I have a usercontrol treeview with report paths.  I have another usercontrol with a reportviewer.  Selecting a report path in the treeview should refresh the reportviewer.
I can "call" the method from the treeview usercontrol for refreshing the reportviewer in the report usercontrol but nothing happens.

I was reading other posts and some seem to suggest a button event to a delegate that will allow the other usercontrol method to be executed.  I'm not using a button event so I'm a bit puzzled.

I thought I could do something like this:

```
 private void treeViewMenu_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    //Get the selected item
    ....
    //Call the method of another user control
    ReportUserControl ruc = new ReportUserControl();
    ruc.RefreshReport();
 }
```

Obviously that didn't work...I know that it shouldn't be too difficult but i am in a brain freeze moment and can't seem to get it working.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: where do you set the reportname (or similar property of user control which stores the name/handle of report to show) for ReportUserControl instance ruc?

Comment: Oops. I messed the method. It should be ruc.RefreshReport(selectedValue) so the report name is actually in the treeview control.  It should pass to the report user control and then it is set using the standard reportviewer setting of reportname, uri and then refresh report. 

I think the problem here is when i debug it, it does go from the treeview control & then to the report user control and it goes through the reportviewer.refresh() just fine but nothing happens.  
So i'm doing something wrong with calling the method and having the refresh happen. I'm just not sure how to fix it.thanks